# The meaning and origin of the phrase "trying to make a spoon spoils a horn"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I was reading [a letter](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yt3aAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=I+am+very+sorry+that+the+pressure+of+other+occupations+has+prevented+me+from+sending+an+earlier+reply+to+your+letter.In+my+opinion+a+man%E2%80%99s+first+duty+is+to+find+a+way+of+supporting+himself,&source=bl&ots=5bLrNdQODz&sig=8OM35cjpeB_lihidR_JeOl2qn7c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_rbmcxejRAhUnj1QKHfuIB8EQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) written by [T. H. Huxley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Henry_Huxley), when I encountered such a paragraph and was stuck by the phrase in bold:

> Nothing is less to be desired than the fate of a young man who, as the Scotch proverb says, in “**trying to make a spoon spoils a horn**,” and becomes a mere hanger-on in literature or in science, when he might have been a useful and a valuable member of Society in other occupations.

I can surmise the meaning of it in that context. Huxley was convincing the young man to strike a balance between commercial work and academic pursuits. To avoid ruining his job while pursuing something he might not deserve.

I have searched the Google, only to find this: "make a spoon or spoil a horn", which is relative to but different from this phrase. Then my question is, what is the origin and the exact meaning of "trying to make a spoon spoils a horn"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard the phrase. But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wooden_spoon) (citing the Encyclopaedia Britannica, 15th Edition) says "The word spoon derives from an ancient word meaning a chip of wood or horn carved from a larger piece."

Comment: Interesting. So the proverb may originate in Scotch when they used horn to make spoon.

Comment: I don't know that it was particularly Scottish to make spoons from horn. ("Scotch" is a kind of whisky, not a language or a people).